# Ant Script Launches a new Terminal MacOs and pauses

Tags: deployment, ant, salesforce

I am trying to run an Ant script from VSCode using Ant Target Runner extension. I am starting it and at some point the script pauses and opens a new terminal that does nothing. At this point I am able to write input into the VSCode terminal (tho nothing happens) and the new one is just a new terminal, I m able to do whatever. I adapted the script to be able to run it in MacOs as before it had cmd instead of the path for the macOs terminal

`<exec failonerror="true" executable="/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal">`

What am i supposed to do to allow the script to run till the end?

type in continue, didnt work
tried closing the process with CMD + C, didnt work
ant help doesnt work, says it doesnt find build.xml

Comment: Have you tried using the attribute `spawn="true"` in the exec task?